# Regex match for contents of <li> element

Tags: regex, parsing, syntax, formatting

I have the following content

```
<li>Title: [...]</li>
```

and I'm looking for regex that will match and replace this so that I can parse it as XML.  I'm just looking to use a regex find and replace inside Sublime Text 2, so I want to match everything in the above example except for the [...] which is the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not extract the content and use it to build the xml rather than trying to mold the wrapper of the content into xml? (or am i mis understanding you?)

```
<li>Title: ([^<]*)<\/li>
```

is the regular expression to extract the content.

Its pretty self explanatory other than the [^<]* which means match any number of characters that is not a "<"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Sublime, but something like this should suffice to get you the contents of the li.  It allows for there being optional extra attributes on the tag.  Make sure and turn off case-sensitivity, incase of LI or Li etc. (lifted straight from http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html ):

```
<li\b[^>]*>(.*?)</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<li>\S*(.*)?</li>`

That should match your string, with the content being capturing group 1.